# Unable to deploy application to App engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been trying to deploy my application that used to be deployed to the App engine cloud using the Google Plugin for eclipse, now I can't deploy it.

I'm getting this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: Deploying <myapp> to Google 
      schedule every 1 second failed to parse
```

However, my application compiled properly and works properly in localhost App engine. What could be the reason that the app won't deploy?

The error doesn't give much information as to what the error is about...

Comment: did u try incrementing the version number in appengine-web.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to schedule a cron task every 1 second? Cron jobs has a minimum interval of a minute.